# Material UI - tooltip displays unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I use material-ui with react in my project. What I want to do is to simply change the tooltip (each tooltip contains an Icon) when certain condition is met.

**ToolTipWrapper.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { Tooltip } from "@material-ui/core";
import { CheckCircle, Error } from "@material-ui/icons";
import { green, deepOrange } from "@material-ui/core/colors";

class TooltipWrapper extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.error.length === 0 ? (
      <Tooltip title="meet all requirements" placement="bottom-start">
        <CheckCircle style={{ color: green[400] }} />
      </Tooltip>
    ) : (
      <Tooltip title="Not meet all requirements" placement="bottom-start">
        <Error style={{ color: deepOrange[400] }} />
      </Tooltip>
    );
  }
}

export default TooltipWrapper;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import TooltipWrapper from "./TooltipWrapper.js";

const styles = {
  fontFamily: "sans-serif",
  textAlign: "center"
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      error: []
    };
  }
  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      error: [123]
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={styles}>
        <TooltipWrapper error={this.state.error} />
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>change</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Please check this demo in codesandbox：[demo link](https://codesandbox.io/s/r0y31y3y2o)

Now the problem is that the second tooltip will not show as expected after changing from the first tooltip by clicking the button. The position of the second tooltip magically moved to the top left, which is quite strange.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using old version of material-ui-next

Comment: No. the dependency in the demo: @material-ui/core 1.2.0; @material-ui/icons 1.1.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this.

```
import React from "react";
import { Tooltip } from "@material-ui/core";
import { CheckCircle, Error } from "@material-ui/icons";
import { green, deepOrange } from "@material-ui/core/colors";

class TooltipWrapper extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Tooltip
        title={
          this.props.error.length === 0
            ? "meet all requirements"
            : "Not meet all requirements"
        }
        placement="bottom-start"
        id="test"
      >
        <span>
          {this.props.error.length === 0 ? (
            <CheckCircle style={{ color: green[400] }} aria-label="test" />
          ) : (
            <Error style={{ color: deepOrange[400] }} aria-label="test" />
          )}
        </span>
      </Tooltip>
    );
  }
}

export default TooltipWrapper;
```

working sandbox version.
https://codesandbox.io/s/w2zkn847m5

Comment: It works! man. Thanks for your help. However, why does adding a <span> to wrap the icon actually work? Could you please explain a little bit. Is it the bug of material UI?

Comment: i think this is bug only. I don't have clear idea is it correct or not but issue i thought is tooltip is calculating placement (top, right, bottom, left) from dom child node so when we are updating state that time we are removing child and adding it again. that time tooltip should recalculate position(with new child) but it is not happening. So i have given tooltip an stable child(span)